# Реализация класса MyIterator - итератора с преобразованием в Java

Tags: java

Вопрос по созданию собственного итератора. Получил следующее задание. 
***Условие:*** Итератор с преобразованием. Реализовать класс-итератор MyIterator. Класс должен реализовывать следующие методы:

- *1. next()* — возвращает следующий элемент, если существует;
- *2. hasNext()* — возвращает true, если остались эл-ты, по которым не было итерации;
- *3. fromIterator* — static-метод. Принимает Iterator, возвращает MyIterator.
- *4. map* — принимает переменную типу функционального интерфейса. Возвращает MyIterator, все элементы которого преобразованы с помощью этого функционального интерфейса.
- *5. forEach* — принимает переменную типу функционального интерфейса. С помощью этой переменной осуществляются над всеми оставшимися элементами класса MyIterator. 
   ***Есть вопрос по пункту 5***. Поскольку MyIterator - класс, который реализует своими методами поведение итератора, то каким образом я могу осуществить какие-либо операции над элементами коллекции, кроме как изменить их? Однако если я верно понимаю суть итератора, то итератор именно позволяет итерироваться по коллекции, не вникая в её содержимое, а никак не менять.
   Каким образом посоветуете выйти из такой ситуации, каким образом достигается указанное в первой строке и в пункте 5 "преобразование"? ***Код моей попытки прилагаю ниже:***

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class MyIterator {
    private Iterator<String> iterator;   // Ссылка на Iterator, типизированный String
    private Function<String, Integer> function;   // Функция преобразования элементов коллекции для текущего экземпляра MyIterator
    private String cursor;

    public MyIterator(Iterator<String> iterator) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
    }

    private MyIterator(Iterator<String> iterator, Function<String, Integer> function) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
        this.function = function;
    }

    public String next() {
        /*if (this.function != null) {
            --- next() выполняет логику function, если this.function не пустой и переходит далее
        }*/
        return cursor = this.iterator.next();
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return this.iterator.hasNext();
    }

    public static MyIterator fromIterator(Iterator<String> iterator) {
        return new MyIterator(iterator);
    }

    public MyIterator map(Function<String, Integer> function) {
        return new MyIterator(this.iterator, function);
    }

    public void forEach(Function<String, Integer> function) {  // ?
        while (hasNext()) {
            this.cursor = this.iterator.next();
            Integer i = function.apply(this.cursor);
            this.cursor = i.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Обычно `forEach()` принимает `Consumer`... И еще одно замечание - ваш `cursor` немного сбивает с толку, т.к. не по назначению используется. Для ваших методов он лишний.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это все таки итератор, он должен уметь работать с любыми типами данных. а не только со стрингами, преобразовывая их в инты. Посему здесь жестко типизировать дженерик не стоит.
Итератор - паттерн проектирования, позволяющий перебирать элементы. Все остальное паттерном не специфицировано. Это не готовое решение, а шаблон и, если вам нужен особый порядок перебора либо преобразование данных, итератор вполне подходит и это никак не нарушает общую концепцию итератора. Вам правильно подсказали, что метод forEach() принимает Consumer. Для того, чтобы определить способ преобразования даннных у вас есть метод map, принимающий Function. Если вы вызываете метод map, то указываете, каким способом вы хотите преобразовать данные, а если вы его не вызываете, то данные не преобразовываются. И это поведение , разумеется, должно распространяться на ваш forEach. Т.е. если вы вызвали map, то forEach прменит преобразование ко всем элементам и, разумеется, отработает Consumer, который вы передали для forEach , в противном случае, если map предварительно вызван не был, то forEach должен без всяких преобразований пройти по всем элементам и вызвать метод accept у Consumer, который ему передали.
Ну и в дополнение, я считаю , что в данном случае мы бы хотели иметь возможность получить стрим, иначе функционал получается каким-то неполноценным. В итоге реализация такова:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class MyIterator <K,V>{

    private final Iterator<K> iterator;
    private final Function<K, V> function;

    public static <K,V> MyIterator<K,V> fromIterator(Iterator<K> iterator) {
        return new MyIterator<>(iterator, k->(V)k);
    }

    private MyIterator(Iterator<K> iterator, Function<K, V> function) {
        this.iterator = iterator;
        this.function = function;
    }

    public MyIterator<K, V> map(Function<K, V> function) {
        return new MyIterator<>(this.iterator, function);
    }

    public Stream<V> stream() {
        return stream(false);
    }

    public Stream<V> parallelStream() {
        return stream(true);
    }

    private Stream<V> stream(boolean isParallel) {
        final Spliterator<K> spliterator = Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, 0);
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, isParallel).map(function);
    }

    public void forEach(Consumer action) {
        while (hasNext()) action.accept(this.next());
    }

    public V next() {
        K element = iterator.next();
        return element==null ? null : function.apply(element);
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterator.hasNext();
    }

}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ясное и подробное объяснение, Дмитрий, Вы очень помогли в понимании! К Вашему исправлению моего кода есть 2 вопроса. Первый: в методе fromIterator лямбда k->(V)k используется, чтобы не получать впоследствии NullPointerException, я верно понимаю? Есть ли иные способы это сделать, или так, как сделали Вы, в данном случае наиболее правильно? Второй:правильно ли я понимаю, что map и forEach чаще всего используются один после другого, а если вызывать forEach - то итератор просто пройдётся по всем элементам с некоторым side-эффектом?

Comment: @Danila ваш кастомный итератор типизирован <K,V> , итератор, который вы принимаете в аргументах типизирован только <K> . это означает, что ваш итератор является гибриодм итератора и интерфейса Function , т.е. принимает одно значение, а возвращает преобразованое. но по условию метод map - отдельный метод. это значит, что если он не вызывается , то итератор не должен ничего преобразовывать. и это одновременно обозначает, что нам надо обеспечить переход дженерика от типа K к типу V (иначе код не скомпилируется).

Comment: @Danila кроме того, наш конструктор приватный, а для создания нашего итератора есть статический метод. тогда вполне логично в конструктор всегда пердавать в качестве аргумента Function и всегда заставлять его отрабатывать. это обеспечит универсальность использования всех методов. просто в случае создания нашего итератора через статический метод мы передаем в качестве Function  некую заглушку, обеспечивающую кастование по сути самого к себе (поскольку в этом случае преобразование не выполняется). это не единственный способ, но мне кажется, что наиболее простой.

Comment: @Danila мне не совсем понятна вторая часть вопроса.... forEach обеспечивает итерирование по всем элементам. в этом его назначение. интерфейс Consumer очень прост public interface Consumer<T> { void accept(T t);} итерироваться просто так бессмысленно, значит нам надо какое-то действие. в данном случае - вывод в консоль. каждый элемент попадает в качестве аргумента Consumer, который ничего не возвращает (он по сигнатуре void).